# how to add a static element to @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I use this code to display a drop down menu list in my View, I would like to add a STATIC value at the beginning of the List with text like None and value as "". How to do it in Razor?

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.Candidates, new SelectList(Model.Candidates, "Value", "Key"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of `DropDownListFor` which takes on a [default string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), e.g.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.Candidates, 
                       new SelectList(Model.Candidates, "Value", "Key"), 
                       "None")
```